# How to accept either a CGFloat or an Array of CGFloats as a function argument?

Tags: swift, function, autolayout, arguments, variadic-functions

I have an auto layout convenience function which stacks views on top of each other. For my spacing parameter, I would like to allow:

- zero spacing between views
- or a single `CGFloat` (all views spaced evenly)
- or an array of `CGFloat`s (different spaces between views)

However, I'm not sure how to define this argument.

```
// Ambiguous
func myconstrainer(_ views : [UIView], spacing : CGFloat = 0){}
func myconstrainer(_ views : [UIView], spacing : [CGFloat]? = nil){}

// Messy
func myconstrainer(_ views : [UIView], spacingA : CGFloat = 0, spacingB: [CGFloat]? = nil){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try *variable number of arguments* like this:

```
func myconstrainer(_ views: [UIView], spacing: CGFloat...) {
    myconstrainer(views, spacing: spacing)
}
```

and provide a simple overload to work with *arrays* as well:

```
func myconstrainer(_ views: [UIView], spacing: [CGFloat]) {
    // Implementation...
}
```

As such, you won't need to put a *single element* in brackets when using even spacing.

Call sites:

```
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3])
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3], spacing: 123)
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3], spacings: 1, 2, 3)
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3], spacings: [1, 2, 3])
```

Some non-obvious notes:

- the default case is nicely covered by calling `CGFloat...` with zero arguments;
- and, since this argument is actually an *array*, we can forward it to the other method without brackets.

Comment: ... and you could add `func myConstrainer(_ views: [UIView])` for the default case... (ps - aren't you missing array brackets in the call in your scalar function?)

Comment: @Grimxn The default case is nicely covered by calling `CGFloat...` with *zero* arguments; and, since this arg is actually an *array,* we can forward it to the other method without brackets ;)

Comment: You're right! Add your comment to the answer, as it's non-obvious!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
func myconstrainer(_ views: [UIView], spacing: CGFloat) {
    myconstrainer(views, spacings: repeatElement(spacing, count: views.count))
}

func myconstrainer<C: Collection>(_ views : [UIView], spacings: C)
    where C.Iterator.Element == CGFloat {
    // actual implementation...
}
```

Call sites:

```
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3], spacing: 123.0)
myconstrainer([view1, view2, view3], spacings: [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to generics, which would bring a world of (I think unnecessary) complexity, you can't do what you want to do, as the type of the parameter needs to be defined to benefit from the type safety Swift is designed to provide.

Why not simply define spacing as an array of CGFloats (as in your second declaration), and default to your first case if spacing.count == 1?

```
func myconstrainer(_ views : [UIView], spacing : [CGFloat]?) {
    if spacing.count == 1 {
        // all views spaced evenly code
    }
    else {
        // different spaces between views code
    }
}
```

PS (you don't need to set an optional parameter to nil)

Comment: I thought about that, I just thought it would be nice to not have to put a single element in brackets when I wanted even spacing, and I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: I think it's the simplest way to implement it. Generics just aren't there yet, IMHO.

Comment: @jglasse I would recommend this too. I was aiming for a more general solution

Comment: I agree yours is more general - just less clear, and frankly, less safe. In my mine, that's the entire point of Swift - clarity with safety.

Comment: @jglasse I completely disagree. As for clarity, the call sites are: `myconstratiner(someViews, spacing: 10)` or `myconstrainer(someViews, spacings: [1, 2, 3])`. It's also perfectly safe.

Comment: To each his own. I think your twin declarations are more verbose and less clear. It's a matter of style.

Comment: @jglasse Twin declarations are perfectly justified, considering you're trying to define two different behaviours.

Comment: Again; a matter of style. My general preference is for less code that I find easier to read; not everyone shares that opinion - some are more focused on having richer APIs, as your implementation provides in this case. To each his own.